# Themeing with drupal. Customized css

Tags: html, css, drupal, drupal-6, themes

This is my first time working properly with CSS. I'm trying to customize a divider that I've inserted into the content block in drupal. In styles.css (see link below) I have the following:

```
#cont-grey {
  background-color:: #393939;
  margin: 20px 30px 20px 30px
  width: 100%;
}
```

The block contents is:

```
<div id="cont-grey">
  <p> Hello </p>
<div>
```

I expect a divider to be printed that contains the word 'Hello' with a +20px margin above and below, and for 'Hello' to be printed 30px in (30px on right as well). The divider should be coloured #393939. I am not getting the output I expected. The divider does not appear to have any special formatting what-so-ever. Please check the page I am using for test purposes below.

Where am I going wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

Links to relevant sources follow:

[My styles.css sheet (hopefully this works)](http://oni-host.com/sites/all/themes/jackson/styles/styles.css)

[The page I am using for test purposes](http://oni-host.com/node/1)

Thanks goes to the developers of drupal's Jackson theme for the CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the extra `:` and try clearing your cache.